# url requesting with different proxies in python

Tags: python, proxy, web-crawler

I am trying to retrive some pages which are google search results and cached. Actually i have two problems for now. I can normally download the first ten results, but cant get it to work to go to "next" 10 pages. I have tried to use regular expressions to find the next control in the page and go from there, i couldn't get it to work. 
But my other problem, which is much more important, is that my ip address is blocked by google that i can no longer view the cached results. So one solution coming to my mind is to use a proxy for making the url requests, and renewing this proxy in some intervals. But i do not have an idea of how to make this job. I tried to search the web for solutions, but i could not come up with a good one. 
I would be very happy if you can give me some advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[5th example](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib2.html)? Or maybe [3rd example](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib.html#examples)?

Comment: i am building my url requests with req=urllib2.request(url,none,headers) and fetching the page with urllib2.urlopen(req).open() . In the examples it uses an opener. is there a way to define such that every url request will be made with a proxy. maybe it sounds simple but i do not know much about python programming.

Comment: Look at the [4th example](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib2.html) - there is an opener being installed for every urlopen call.